# Python code for resource groups code deletion in azure using Resource group tags

Tags: python, azure, azure-resource-group

I am trying to delete the resource groups and resources in it using python code. 
I have tried this in powershell and it works perfect. Now my organization wanted in Python. I am really new to python and trying to write the code and failed .

Here is the powershell code for the same. Can anyone help on getting the code in python.

Thanks in advance.

```
 $rgs = Get-AzureRmResourceGroup;
```

# $rgs=Get-AzureRmResourceGroup -name "TestResourceGroupToClean1";

```
if(!$rgs)
{ 
    Write-Output "No resource groups in your subscription"; 
} 
else{


    Write-Output "You have $($(Get-AzureRmResourceGroup).Count) resource groups in your subscription"; 
    foreach($resourceGroup in $rgs)
    { 
        $name=  $resourceGroup.ResourceGroupName; 
     if($resourceGroup.Tags.ExpiryDate)
     {
    try{
         $ResourceGroupTagDate=[datetime]::ParseExact($resourceGroup.Tags.ExpiryDate,'MM/dd/yyyy',$null)
         $count = (Get-AzureRmResource | where { $_.ResourceGroupName -match $name }).Count;
            if($ResourceGroupTagDate.Date -lt $today.Date)
            { 
                $subject="Automated Mail from Resource Group Cleaner"
                $body="Resource Group $($resourceGroup.ResourceGroupName) including resources has been deleted"
                Write-Output "The resource group $name has $count resources. Deleting it..."; 
                Remove-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $resourceGroup.ResourceGroupName -Force; 
                Write-Output "The resource group $name and $count resources. Deleted..";
                Send-MailMessage -To 'XXXX@XXXXXXXX.com' -Subject $subject -Body $body -UseSsl  -Port 587 -SmtpServer 'smtp.office365.com' -From $userid -Credential $creds 
            }

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

> Here is the Error I am getting ############################# Failed Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Temp\kukzwo13.tgf\9bd12580-5780-4109-abab-66e88fb4df87", line 59, in  if not item.tags['ExpiryDate']:KeyError: 'ExpiryDate'

In python code, we need to check the key is valid for the dictionary. I have done a demo for deleting the resource group by tags with python code.

```
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from azure.mgmt.resource import ResourceManagementClient
import datetime
from datetime import time

# Tenant ID for your Azure Subscription
TENANT_ID = 'tenant id '
# Your Service Principal App ID
CLIENT = 'client id'
# Your Service Principal Password
KEY = 'scret key'
subscription_id = 'subscrptionId'
credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(client_id=CLIENT, secret=KEY, tenant=TENANT_ID)
client = ResourceManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)
groups = client.resource_groups.list()
null_variable = None
for item in groups:
    if item.tags != null_variable:
            if 'ExpiryDate' in item.tags:
                expiryDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(item.tags["ExpiryDate"],"%m/%d/%Y")
                timediff = expiryDate < datetime.datetime.today()
                if timediff:
                    print(item.tags["ExpiryDate"])
                    print(item.name)
                    client.resource_groups.delete(item.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start with the sample page:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/resource-manager-python-resources-and-groups

and the docs for support
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/azure/?view=azure-python

Comment: I have been referring to this. I am able to get the list of resource groups , But i am not able to get the particular tagged resource groups. Here is my python...........I have been referring to this and able to get the list of resource groups but i am not able to get the tags of that.......

Comment: Here is my code 
##########################
resources.print('List Resource Groups')
for item in client.resource_groups.list():
    print(item)
    GROUP_NAME=item.name
    print(GROUP_NAME)
    print(item.tags)
    if (item.tags) is not None:
        print("tags are not none")
        if not item.tags['ExpiryDate']:
            print("No tag named ExpiryDate")
        else:
            ExpiryDate=item.tags['ExpiryDate']
            print("\tExpiryDate: {}".format(ExpiryDate))
    else:
        print("No Tags")
#############################################

Comment: Here is the Error I am getting 
#############################
Failed
Traceback (most recent call last):  File "C:\Temp\kukzwo13.tgf\9bd12580-5780-4109-abab-66e88fb4df87", line 59, in <module>    if not item.tags['ExpiryDate']:KeyError: 'ExpiryDate'

Comment: You initial message is not Python, it's Powershell :). If you want better help, you should edit your message with your Python code.